# how to enable all the dates,mont and year in angular bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular bootstrap date picker as shown in  https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker ( using the popup one).
there certain dates,months and year are disabled i want all of them to be  enabled there is no restriction on any of them how to enable it

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the `date-disabled`  option. By default its set to null implies all dates are enabled.

**Edit**:

Working plnkr is here http://plnkr.co/edit/3NlxBCQGKyAQm1B4EP0t?p=preview
Its full edit of the Angular UI datepicker example (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker). 
Check the the inline example. All dates/year/months are enabled. `min-date` disables any earlier dates. Don't specify it and all dates are enabled.

Comment: thank you can u please let me know how enable years an month as well if possible please create a plunker its urgent